# SQL - Does a range fall within consecutive ranges

Tags: sql, oracle, range

I'm really stumped here...

Let's say I have this table of "valid numbers" with columns BEGIN_NUM and END_NUM to represent a range of valid numbers.  The table would look something like this:

```
ID BEGIN_NUM END_NUM
-- --------- -------
 A       1      10         
 B      11      20
 C      21      30
 D      55      70
```

We are given a begin-number and an end-number of a range.  I need to develop a SQL query to see if that range of numbers are all valid numbers.

Easy case:  given 2 and 8 as our begin and end to our range, this would pass since it falls within the range of Row A.

Hard cases:  (#1) given 5 and 15, this would pass, since this falls within Row A and Row B, which are essentially continuations of each other making one big range that spans two rows. (1-10 & 11-20 = 1-20).

(#2) given 5 and 25, this would also pass for the same reason as (#1), except that it spans a couple of rows instead of just two. (1-10 & 11-20 & 21-30 = 1-30)

(#3) given 27 and 57, this would FAIL because even though the begin and end numbers fall within a range, there is a gap between Row C and Row D (so this would make numbers 31-54 in our given range invalid).

I really don't have to return any data with this query, just show that the range contains all valid numbers.  Using Oracle if that matters.

Here is what I have so far:

```
select count(*) 
from (select start_num, end_num
    from ae_valid_vendor_nums
    where '5' BETWEEN start_num AND end_num) tbl1,
 (select start_num, end_num
    from ae_valid_vendor_nums
    where '25'  BETWEEN start_num AND end_num) tbl2
where (tbl1.end_num - tbl2.start_num = -1) 
OR (tbl1.start_num = tbl2.start_num AND tbl1.end_num = tbl2.end_num)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Edited - using Oracle

Comment: Updated with what I have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fun little problem.  The idea is to count the overlap within each group, sum the overlaps, and then compare to the actual range.  The following query does this with some examples.  It outputs a bit more than you are asking for, but that should help you understand how it works:

```
with ValidNumbers as (
     select 1 as begin_num, 10 as end_num from dual union all
     select 11, 20 from dual union all
     select 21, 30 from dual union all
     select 55, 70 from dual
    )
select v_begin, v_end,
       sum(1 + (case when v_end >= vn.end_num then vn.end_num else v_end end) -
           (case when v_begin >= vn.begin_num then v_begin else vn.begin_num end)
          ) as SumInRecords,
       max(1 + v_end - v_begin) as TheRange,
       (case when sum(1 + (case when v_end >= vn.end_num then vn.end_num else v_end end) -
                      (case when v_begin >= vn.begin_num then v_begin else vn.begin_num end)
                     ) =
                   max(1 + v_end - v_begin)
             then 'All' else 'Missing'
         end)
from ValidNumbers vn cross join
     (select 2 as v_begin, 8 as v_end from dual union all
      select 2, 18 from dual union all
      select 2, 28 from dual union all
      select 2, 38 from dual
     ) const
where v_begin <= vn.end_num and
      v_end >= vn.begin_num
group by v_begin, v_end;
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use a tally table and then compare the tally count to the difference of the two end points (plus one because it's inclusive)

This for example

```
WITH validnumbers 
     AS (SELECT 1  AS begin_num, 10 AS end_num FROM   dual 
         UNION ALL SELECT 11, 20          FROM   dual 
         UNION ALL SELECT 21, 30          FROM   dual 
         UNION ALL SELECT 55, 70          FROM   dual), 
     tally 
     AS (SELECT LEVEL num 
         FROM   dual 
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 100 
         ORDER  BY LEVEL), 
     test 
     AS (SELECT t.num 
         FROM   validnumbers v 
                inner join tally t 
                        ON v.begin_num <= t.num 
                           AND v.end_num >= t.num 
         WHERE  t.num >= 27 
                AND t.num <= 57) 
SELECT Count(num), 
       (57 - 27) + 1
FROM   test
```

Produces this result a correct fail case

```
COUNT(NUM)  (57-27)+1
---------- ----------
         7         31
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/25114)

substituting 57 and 27 with 25 and  5 gives us a correct pass

```
COUNT(NUM)   (25-5)+1
---------- ----------
        21         21
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/25112)